# Python compile() function : get line number and last error message

Tags: python, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using compile function to compile a python string. How do I read the last summary of compile error and also the line number for the error.

```
pystr = '''
print('abc')
print(abc)
'''
try:
  compile(pystr, '', 'eval')
except Exception as e:
  #print(e)
  print(sys.exc_info())

######outputs##############
(<class 'SyntaxError'>, SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('', 3, 'print(abc)\n')), <traceback object at 0x02BB7120>)

# I would need 1) last error message - 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax', 2) line number '3'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use below code to read all the contents of object e. There we will find few attributes with error details:

```
pystr = '''
print('abc')
print(abc)
'''
try:
    compile(pystr, '', 'eval')
except Exception as e:

    # print all attributes
    for attr in dir(e):
        print("e.%s = %r" % (attr, getattr(e, attr)))

    #useful attributes:
    print(e.lineno)
    print(e.msg)
    print(e.text)
```